# Get Logical Names of Installed POS Devices

Tags: .net, pos-for-.net

I am going to make a POS App using .NET with POS for .NET. Is there any way to list logical names of installed devices on the machine then I can pass selected logical name to GetDevice method

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to dive into the registry, here is another way:

```
PosExplorer explorer = new PosExplorer();    
List<String[]> foundLogicalNames = new List<String[]>();   // String[0] will hold device type, String[1] will hold logical name

foreach (DeviceInfo deviceInfo in explorer.GetDevices())   // This will get ALL device types
    foreach (String logicalName in deviceInfo.LogicalNames)
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logicalName))
            foundLogicalNames.Add(new String[2] { deviceInfo.Type, logicalName });  // Only add devices with logical names set
```

At this point the variable ***foundLogicalNames*** should contain a list of all the *accessible* devices with a logical name previously setup.

Now we can select the device we want from this list:

```
DeviceInfo selectedDevice;

if (foundLogicalNames.Count > 0)   // Ensure we have found some logical names set on our system
{
    int desiredDeviceIndex = selectDesiredDeviceFromFoundLogicalNames();   // user implemented function, get integer index into foundLogicalNames of desired device
    selectedDevice = explorer.GetDevice(foundLogicalNames[desiredDeviceIndex][0], foundLogicalNames[desiredDeviceIndex][1]);    // [0] = device type, [1] = logical name
    ...     
    // continue to Open(), Claim() etc
}
```

Comment: May I ask how can I setup a logical Name? I am new to Microsoft's POS, and I am trying to use an EPSON printer which requires a logical name.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the registry tree under the key HKLM/SOFTWARE/OLEforRetail

the actual drivers ocx/dll will be listed under the relevant sections of the ServiceInfo sub key
and the logical names will be under the relevant sections of the ServiceOPOS sub key

That is if the hardware manuf. adheres to the OPos standard.